# Running jmeter .jmx tests locally using windows command line giving illegal argument exception

Tags: windows, command-line, jmeter, whitespace

Using below command to run the tests on windows cmd - Is there any initialization required in jmeter for doing so.

jmeter -n -t C:/Users/meiyer/Desktop/LOAD TOOLS/jmeter samples/50users10count.jmx

stacktrace -

```
2016/08/29 15:17:18 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2016/08/29 15:17:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from:   
C:\Users\meiyer\Documents\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-
3.0\bin\user.properties 
2016/08/29 15:17:18 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from:    
C:\Users\meiyer\Documents\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-
3.0\bin\system.properties 
2016/08/29 15:17:18 FATAL - jmeter.JMeter: An error occurred:  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown arg: TOOLS/jmeter
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.initializeProperties(JMeter.java:746)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:385)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
```

Comment: hello, any feedback on answer ? thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue comes from the space between LOAD and TOOLS.

Use quote around the path:

> jmeter -n -t "C:/Users/meiyer/Desktop/LOAD TOOLS/jmeter samples/50users10count.jmx"